# 'logical errors' or 'logistical errors'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

I am reading a novel which has lots of those *lol*, where some of the events do not make sense at all.

Should I call them logical errors? or logistical errors?

Comment: You may also be looking for the term *continuity error*, which refers specifically to inconsistencies in detail from one scene to the next (e.g. Alice is wearing a red shirt on page one, and a blue shirt on page two, having had no opportunity or reason to change).

Comment: Given that it's a novel it's hard to know what you mean by "logical". Do you have any examples?

Comment: Lots of those *lol*, where some of the events do not make sense at all. That sentence seems to describe/be a [*non sequitur*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur).

Comment: When you're talking more about nonsensical events rather than facts, you can also be talking about plot holes.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plot_hole (although the analogy there with pot hole is not well taken.)

Answer (score 3):

> *[Logic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/logic)*

means:-

> 1. the science that investigates the principles governing correct or reliable inference.
> 2. a particular method of reasoning or argumentation: We were unable to
>      follow his logic.
> 3. the system or principles of reasoning applicable to any branch of knowledge or study.
> 4. reason or sound judgment, as in utterances or actions: There wasn't much logic in her move.
> 5. convincing forcefulness; inexorable truth or persuasiveness: the irresistible logic of the facts.

whereas *[logistics](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/logistics)* means:-

> 1. The aspect of military operations that deals with the procurement, distribution, maintenance, and replacement of materiel and personnel.
> 2. The management of the details of an operation.

so unless your novel is dealing with the details of supply management and the failings of the characters in that subject, it is overwhelmingly likely that it contains, or is about, errors of *logic*.

Answer (score 2):

In fiction, sequences where events don't make sense usually are called *[implausible](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/implausible#Adjective)* (or an *[implausibility](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/implausibility#Noun)*) rather than being called  “logic errors”.  As long as characters are acting consistently and in ways that are supported by events, they can do illogical things and still be believable and plausible.  However, if a character who has been portrayed as organized and motivated suddenly begins doing stupid things because the author needs to move the plot along, the result is implausibility.  Similarly if a weak character suddenly becomes strong, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

They can be called as logical errors.

Logistics refer to the organization of moving, housing, and supplying troops and equipment. I don't think this term is suitable for the novel you are reading.

So, here the word logistical errors is not suitable.

Incorrectness of reasoning or belief is called as logical error.

Hence, the term "**logical error**" is apt here.